# Examine whether the following set is a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, operations-research

So i am an undergrad student and this question was asked in an assignment

Examine if
$\{(x, y)\in \Bbb R^2 \mid 2x+3y≤6,2x+3y≥6, x≥0, y≥0\}$
is a convex set

After solving the constraints, we come to the conclusion that the set is basically a line segment joining points (3, 0) and (0, 2) and since  a line segment is  convex  the given set is a convex set. Or we can also use the theorem that intersection of two convex sets is a convex set. Now the two constraints in the set individually give us 2 half planes and since half planes are a convex set then their intersection will also be a convex set. Are these above reasons sufficient to prove that the given set is convex?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: After solving the constraints, we come to the conclusion that the set is basically a line segment joining points (3, 0) and (0, 2) and since  a line segment is  convex  the given set is a convex set. Or we can also use the theorem that intersection of two convex sets is a convex set. Now the two constraints in the set individually give us 2 half planes and since half planes are a convex set then their intersection will also be a convex set.@SiongThyeGoh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection of convex set is convex is indeed the result that you need.

Each of the constraints is a half space which is convex, hence the intersection must be convex.

In general, a polyhedral which are intersection of half spaces are convex.